# Parse error in hive query in CASE statment with GROUP BY clause

Tags: hive

I have two urls format in my input that I need to parse

URL's

abc.com/abcd?id=123

xyz.com/abcd/id123

After parsing I need to store `id=123` and `id123` in database

Here is my hive query to parse the url and

```
insert into table table2
select  
CASE
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="abc.com"
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'HOST') as host,
    split(url_domain,'\\?id=')[1] as id,
    count(*) 
    from table1
    GROUP BY parse_url(url_domain, 'HOST'), split(url_domain,'\\?id=')[1]    
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="xyz.com"
THEN
    parse_url(url_domain,'HOST') as host,
    split(url_domain,'\\/id')[1] as id,
    count(*) 
    from table1
    GROUP BY parse_url(url_domain, 'HOST'), split(url_domain,'\\/id=')[1]
END
ORDER BY host, id DESC limit 100;
```

But when I execute the query it gives the following error

`FAILED: ParseException line 6:33 missing KW_END at 'as' near ']'`

I tried removing id alias and other combination but didn't work

**Info:**
I hive I can't use alias in Group by clause as its hive limitation

`split(url_domain,'\\?id=')[1] as id`

if I use `GROUP BY id` it gives error but this works fine `GROUP BY parse_url(url_domain, 'HOST')`

so because of this I could not move the GROUP BY outside the CASE statement

---

**Update**

```
insert into table table2
select  
CASE
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="abc.com"
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'HOST') as host, split(url_domain,'\\?id=')[1] as id,
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="xyz.com"
THEN
    parse_url(url_domain,'HOST') as host, split(url_domain,'\\/id')[1] as id,
END
count(*) 
from table1
GROUP BY parse_url(url_domain, 'HOST')
ORDER BY host, id DESC limit 100;
```

Same error :(

Error Log

```
NoViableAltException(262@[146:1: selectExpression : ( expression | tableAllColumns );])
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectExpression(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:2882)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectItem(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:2266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectList(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:1052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectClause(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectClause(HiveParser.java:31425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regular_body(HiveParser.java:29083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatement(HiveParser.java:28968)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:28762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:938)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
FAILED: ParseException line 6:33 missing KW_END at 'as' near ',' in select expression
line 7:0 cannot recognize input near 'WHEN' 'parse_url' '(' in select expression
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with hive, but are you allowed to have what appears to be a subquery in the THEN condition?  I know in transact sql there has to be a single value there.

Comment: Its possible as per the forums that I have read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4661 I am also new to hive so not 100% sure

Comment: Can you pull the "ID" you are selecting within the case statement, out of the case statement? It is the same in both conditions. Another thing I noticed in the update is a missing comma between the end of the case statement and the subsequent "count".

Comment: I meant pull the host out rather than the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it by creating two separate `CASE` statement one for `parse_url` and one for `split_url`. As hive has problem taking alias in `GROUP BY` clause so this was the only way

**Final Hive SQL Statement**

```
insert into table table2 select parse_url(url_domain,'HOST') as host,
CASE
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="abc.com" 
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'QUERY','id')
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="def.com"
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'QUERY','packageName')
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="xyz.com"
THEN
    split(split(url_domain,'\\/id')[1],'\\?')[0]
ELSE
    "NULL"
END as appid,
count(*)
from table1
group by parse_url(url_domain,'HOST'),
CASE
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="abc.com" 
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'QUERY','id')
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="def.com"
THEN 
    parse_url(url_domain,'QUERY','packageName')
WHEN parse_url(url_domain,'HOST')="xyz.com"
THEN
    split(split(url_domain,'\\/id')[1],'\\?')[0]
ELSE
"NULL"
END
order by host,appid DESC LIMIT 100;
```